# MySQL PHP: Return rows based on a column

Tags: php, mysql

This seems easy but haven't found the magic search term yet.

One table

```
ID | UserID | Mod_number

1      43      1
2      43      2
3      43      3 
4      43      4
5      55      1
6      55      2
```

I want to return a query that looks like:

```
UserID | Mod_1&ID | Mod_2&ID ....  [EDITED below]

43     |   1&1    |  2&2 ....
55     |   1&5    |  2&6 ....
```

The Mod numbers are fixed (there are 7 of them).

The concatenation I know how to do, it's the rearranging values into rows that's tripping me up.

Any help or direction would be awesome, thanks! :)

======================
**EDIT:**

Hoping that the downvote was lack of clarity than quality of question - let me try to explain better.

This is for an assessment tool being developed in Joomla.  Each module (section) gets checked off by a supervisor.  When that happens there's an ID, a UserID, and a ModID recorded (among other data).

That results in a table that looks like this:

```
ID | UserID | Mod_number

1      43      1
2      43      2
3      43      3 
4      43      4
5      55      1
6      55      2
7      61      2
8      61      4
```

Each UserID is a user.  I need to form this into an array where each row is one user and also contains the ID for each module.  I think this presentation might be clearer (skipping the concatenation):

```
UserID | ID_M1 | ID_M2 | ID_M3 |ID_M4

43     |   1    |   2  |   3   |   4
55     |   5    |   6  |  
61     |        |   7  |       |   8
```

So that now there's one unique UserID per row (could be considered a key) with the ID recorded for each Module number.  As an array that would probably look something like `array(UserID=>array(ID_M1, ID_M2, ID_M3, ID_M4))`.  But getting that data into this is befuddling me.

Also, if you have other suggestions on structuring the data that would make it easier I'd love to hear - I'm a bit new to php/mysql/Joomla dev and there could be a simpler way of doing this.

Hope that makes more sense, thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Edited above, let me know if that makes more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a really ugly query where you `GROUP BY UserID` and then do some complex string manipulations, I suppose. But you'd be better off just getting this data as is and then restructuring it into an array in PHP.

```
$rows; // say this is an array direct from the db with id, user_id, mod_id fields
$grouped = array(); // we will build this array from your data

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    if (!isset($grouped[$row['user_id']]))
    {
        $grouped[$row['user_id']] = array();
    }

    $grouped[$row['user_id']]['mod_' . $row['mod_id']] = $row['id'];
}
```

Now, when this has run, you should have an array, keyed by user_id, containing arrays keyed like 'mod_1', 'mod_2', etc. where the value is the 'id'. I think this is basically what you want.

Comment: I've been playing with this all day but haven't had too much luck - would you have any quasi code that I can try out and run with? Thanks!

Comment: (Quasi code in php, the logic of what to do is tripping me up a bit)

Answer (score 2):

This is a pivot table. you can look at this for help. http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#787

Comment: That's what it is!  I figured this had to be done fairly often, very useful resource - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about following?

```
SELECT 
UserID,
IF (ID > 0 && Mod_Number = 1, ID, null) ID_M1,
IF (ID > 0 && Mod_Number = 2, ID, null) ID_M2,
IF (ID > 0 && Mod_Number = 3, ID, null) ID_M3,
IF (ID > 0 && Mod_Number = 4, ID, null) ID_M4
from <YourTable>
```

Here the IF  ID_M part you can programatically generate from PHP as I think that's going to be dynamic.

Comment: I tried out @Elijah's first.  I see where you're going with this though, thanks for another approach!

Comment: hmm, good. Basically above sql snippet will just fetch you things from database avoiding you from much processing later on... :-)

I made a mistake by putting up Mod_Number = 4 for all the columns and there were some typo just corrected them. I think it should make some more sense now.

Good luck.!

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should help:

SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) as MOD_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(mod_number) as MOD_Number
FROM  GROUP BY user_id

Comment: I tried this - it didn't quite get it in the form I needed it in.  Let me know if my edits above make more sense - this may be close but I could be confused on applying it.

Comment: Yes, now after your edit it's much clear. I have posted another answer I think that should match your requirement.